# C++ append int to wstring

Tags: c++

Before(using ASCII) i was using std::string as buffer like this:

```
std::string test = "";
int value = 6;
test.append("some string");
test.append((char*)value, 4);
test.append("some string");
```

with expected value in test:

> "some srtring\x6\x0\x0\x0somestring"

Now i am tring to use Unicode and i wanna keep the same "code" but trubles happens:

```
std::wstring test = "";
int value = 6;
test.append("some string");
test.append((wchar_t*)value, 4); (buffer overflow cause reading 8 bytes)
test.append("some string");
```

How can i append bytes like in std::string?
Doing:

```
std::wstring test = "";
int value = 6;
test.append("some string");
test.append((wchar_t*)value, 2);
test.append("some string");
```

Solve partially the problem cause after i can't append bools.

EDIT:
i can even use wstringstream if a binary copy is applied.(normally not)

Comment: You don't "use Unicode" by just flipping to `std::wstring`.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::to_string` and `std::to_wstring`? (and use `+` for concat)

Comment: Casts are usually a bad idea. C-style casts are usually an even worse idea. Had you used a C++ cast, you'd find that `static_cast<char*>(value)` won't compile. Generally, a `static_cast` is at least safe. By not compiling, at least you might be deterred from trying to cast like that. `(char*)value` takes the bytes and reinterprets them as characters. Are you sure that's what you really want? Of course not, but the cast doesn't tell you that, like `reinterpret_cast` does.

Comment: i need a "binary" dynamic buffer, where i can add the real size of types(bool 1, int 4 etc)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: And you don't use ASCII by using `std::string`, either :)

Comment: sorry, guys, but i refer from that:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx . A means ANSI API, W means UNICODE API...there are just different type of UNICODE(16,32). This case (wide) its UTF16.

Comment: @Ixiodor It's wrong. Microsoft have some funny ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing unicode and [character encodings](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). An `std::string` can represent unicode code points just fine, using the UTF-8 encoding.

Windows uses the UTF-16LE (or UTF-16 with a BOM, I believe) encoding to represent unicode glyphs. Most others use UTF-8.

An `std::string` which is encoded in UTF-8 and which uses only ASCII characters can actually be interpreted as an ASCII string. This is the beauty of UTF-8. It's a natural extension.

Anyway,

> i need a "binary" dynamic buffer, where i can add the real size of types(bool 1, int 4 etc)

An `std::vector<uint8_t>` is probably more suitable for this task. It communicates that it is not something human-readable, per se. If you need to embed strings into this buffer, make sure that `sizeof(char) == sizeof(uint8_t)` on the platform, and then just write the data as-is to this buffer.

If you're saving this buffer on one machine and try to read it on another machine, you have to take care of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) too.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I'll search more about that.

Answer (score 0):

You make a function that reads the stuff you want to put:

```
void putBytes(std::wstring& s, char* c, int numBytes)
{
    while (numBytes-- > 0)
        s += (wchar_t)*c++;
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
int value = 65;
putBytes(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a IStream is a proper way to do this...i'll make an interface to handle different types. I was abusing std::string for an easy "dynamic binary array", with std::wstring this is not possible,for many reasons but most silly one is that require at least 2 bytes, so no room for a bool